# How to derive the characteristic function of a polar coordinates representation of a bivariate normal

Tags: normal-distribution, bivariate, characteristic-function

Suppose to have a bivariate normal variable $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)$ with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. I move from $\mathbf{x}$ to $(\theta,r)$ where $x_1 = r \cos \theta$ and $x_2 = r \sin \theta$: the representation in polar coordinates of $\mathbf{x}$.
My question is:  is it possible to derive the characteristic function of $(\theta,r)$? and the characteristic function of $\theta$?

Comment: The characteristic function is of the distribution of $x$, not of the parameters.  The distribution function parameters appear in the characteristic function... so saying "derive the characteristic function of $(\theta, r)$" makes no sense.   If you have a 1-1 map from $(\theta, r)$ to $(\mu, \Sigma)$ you can simply substitute $(\theta, r)$ into the ch.f. in the obvious way to get the ch.f. *in terms of* $(\theta, r)$, which may be what you want.

Comment: @jbowman I can't follow any of that comment.  Because $(\theta, r)$ is explicitly given as a bivariate *random variable,* of course it has a characteristic function $(s,t)\to E[\exp(is\theta+itr)].$ And how does this "simple substitution" work with characteristic functions? I see no "obvious way" at all!